# 24 or 27" UHD/4K monitor for developer. Dell U2718Q?

Tags: monitors, development, uhd

I'm looking for an external monitor to attach to my laptop in portrait mode (known as "pivot"). I use it for coding, reading web pages, and reading/editing documents.  Not gaming.

GPU is Nvidia Quadro P4000.

I'd like to buy the latest product/technology, rather than something which has been on the market for 3 years.  [4K Monitor for programming](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6845/4k-monitor-for-programming) is a bit dated now at 18 months ago.

https://www.scorptec.com.au/product/monitors/4k-monitors lets you sort by what's new.

Looks like the newest they list is Dell U2718Q. There's the P2415Q, which has been around a while, but has newer variants.

I'm open to that. I've also found Asus PB27UQ and PB287Q (the latter is not IPS - but its cheap enough that maybe that doesn't matter?).

And of course https://www.eizoglobal.com/press/releases/htmls/ev2785.html

So what's the best choice, weighing price and quality? :-)

Comment: This is a bit broad, we don't know your specific requirements to be able to recommend one model over another. If your only concern is price, then you can find your answer yourself. Do you want IPS or not? Side note: I've never used a 4k monitor before, I don't know what the appeal is exactly so knowing what you are trying to accomplish besides the broad "reading text on a screen" would help a lot.

Comment: Part of it is/was wanting 4K "just in case" and also from a holding its value point of view.  $100 or so extra to get IPS in the end, so why not...  thanks for your comment :-)

Comment: On another note, at only 200 quid in the UK, the AOC Q3279VWF would also be an excellent choice for anyone visiting this thread. It runs at a resolution of 1440p@75z, useful for light gaming too. It's as good quality as it is just huge!

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I did buy the Dell U2718Q, when it was on sale.

Very happy with it.

My laptop and the U2718Q are both capable of 3840x2160, but I'm running them at 2560x1600.  U2718Q via the mini display port cable it shipped with.

The text size and sharpness works well for me.